# jQuery.. how to append text to the end of existing text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question... maybe? Basically what I want to do is insert text to the end of a URL loaded on the page. So on my page I would have something like...

```
<a href="myurl.html">My Url</a>
```

And what I want is for text to be appended after the file extension on a click event. So after the click it should look like..

```
<a href="myurl.html#something">My Url</a>

$('a').click(function(){
  //add text to url
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `href` attribute using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("href", $(this).prop("href") + "#something");
});
```

or

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "#something");
});
```